# How to add custom attribute to custom tab?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have added a new tab to customer admin area using info provided [here](http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/how-to-add-tab-in-customer-information-in-magento-admin/)

Now i want to add attributes to this custom tab. I have installed an extension for customer attributes but it adds the attributes to **Account Information** tab. How to get this done?